# Excel 2007 VBA Export range as jpg file is truncating picture

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, charts

I have a workbook with many different ranges of data with 77 lines or more. I need to copy them and save as JPG files, which will be used by another application.

Below is the example of code that I'm using for that. It works fine for ranges with up to 68 lines, but for ranges with more than that, the file shows up to around 1360 pixels height of the range and the rest of it (the bottom part) is white.

```
Sub Create_jpg()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim rgExp As Range

    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ScorecardJPEGs\"

    Sheets("LocalMetrics").Select

    Set rgExp = Range("A1:AL77")

    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
                                      Width:=(rgExp.Width - 10), Height:=(rgExp.Height - 5))
        .Name = "ChartTempEXPORT"
        .Activate
    End With

    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartTempEXPORT").Chart.Export FileName:=MyPath & "Scorecard.jpg", _
                                                             Filtername:="jpg"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartTempEXPORT").Delete

End Sub
```

I verified that the creation of the chart and the paste looks fine, as I removed the line of code that deletes the chart at the end and apparently the picture on the chart was ok. But when the file is created, the bottom part of the picture simply vanished, and there is a white space there.
This happened to all ranges with many rows.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your paste range is larger than your paste space. I couldn't get excel to get the blank space you described but the following code made it so the macro could handle more than 77 rows.

```
Sub Create_jpg()
Const fColumn As String = "A": Const lColumn As String = "AL"
Const maxRange As Integer = 77
Dim tempRowEnd As Integer: tempRowEnd = 0: Dim tempRowBegin As Integer: tempRowBegin = 0
Dim loopCount As Integer: loopCount = 0
Dim MyPath As String
Dim rgExp As Range
Dim lRowCount As Long:
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ScorecardJPEGs\"
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lRowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do
    tempRowBegin = tempRowEnd + 1 'chooses the first row in the selection
    tempRowEnd = tempRowEnd + maxRange 'chooses the end row in the selection
    Set rgExp = Range(fColumn & tempRowBegin & ":" & lColumn & tempRowEnd)

    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
                                  Width:=(rgExp.Width - 10), Height:=(rgExp.Height - 5))
        .Name = "ChartTempEXPORT"
        .Activate
    End With

    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartTempEXPORT").Chart.Export Filename:=MyPath & "Scorecard" & loopCount & ".jpg", _
                                                     Filtername:="jpg"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartTempEXPORT").Delete

    loopCount = loopCount + 1 'increments count for naming convention
Loop Until tempRowEnd > lRowCount

End Sub
```

Let me know how that works out for you.